# Cannot display text from text box while button click?

Tags: javascript, html

I have created the `button(click on me)` using the html. When the button is clicked the `textbox` along with another `button(show)` is displayed on the screen. The value written in the `textbox` is shown when the show button is clicked. The `textbox` and show button is hidden. Again when i `click (click on me ) button` the `textbox` and show button is displayed. But when i write the text in `textbox` and click the show button this time text wont be displayed. That means first time text will be displayed but not after that. I want to display the text repeatedly. I am new to `javascript` so please help me. I also want to drag and drop the displayed text anywhere on the screen.

*Try.html*

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>


<form name="frm">

<input type="button" value="Click on Me" id="button" onClick="display();">
</form>

<div id="responce"></div>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

var box="textBox"

function display()
{
document.getElementById('responce').innerHTML+='<center><input type="text" id="'+box+'" /></center>';
document.getElementById('responce').innerHTML+='<center><INPUT type="button" value="Show" id="btn2" onClick="visual();"/></center>';
}
</script>

<script>
function visual()
{   

var dis=document.getElementById(box).value ;
document.getElementById('responce').innerHTML+=document.getElementById(box).id;;
document.getElementById('responce').innerHTML+='<br><center>nilav '+dis+'</center></br>';
document.getElementById(box).style.visibility='hidden';
document.getElementById('btn2').style.visibility='hidden';


}
</script>

</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `</script>

</script>`  no proper closing of script tag. Please verify this first

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the display function you are creating the text box & button every time you invoke the function, I just added a checking if the object is already present it'll just change the visibility.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>


<form name="frm">

<input type="button" value="Click on Me" id="button" onClick="display();">
</form>

<div id="responce"></div>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

var box="textBox"

function display()
{
    if(!document.getElementById(box)) {
        document.getElementById('responce').innerHTML+='<center><input type="text" id="'+box+'" /></center>';
        document.getElementById('responce').innerHTML+='<center><INPUT type="button" value="Show" id="btn2" onClick="visual();"/></center>';
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById(box).style.visibility='visible';
        document.getElementById('btn2').style.visibility='visible';
    }
}
</script>

<script>
function visual()
{   

var dis=document.getElementById(box).value ;
document.getElementById('responce').innerHTML+=document.getElementById(box).id;;
document.getElementById('responce').innerHTML+='<br><center>nilav '+dis+'</center></br>';
document.getElementById(box).style.visibility='hidden';
document.getElementById('btn2').style.visibility='hidden';


}
</script>

</body>

</html>
```